# dataframe manupulation using ddply

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I am having a dataframe named output
[output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIxN3.png)

I want to generate mode(most repeating) of `code` for each distinct `patientID` and count of unique `patientID` with the above `code` for each distinct `zipcode`.

I tried this:

```
ddply(output,~zipcode,summarize,max=mode(code))
```

this code will generate mode of `code` for each distinct `zipcode`...but I want to generate mode of `code` for distinct `patientID` within distinct `zipcode`.

```
output=data.frame(code=c("E78.5","N08","E78.5","I65.29","Z68.29","D64.9"),patientID=c("34423","34423","34423","34423","34424","34425"),zipcode=c(00718,00718,00718,00718,00718,00719),city=c("NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO"))
```

```html
my output=
zipcode most_rep_code patient_count
1     718         E78.5             1
2     719         D64.9             1
```

Comment: please include a reproducible data sample rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @nycrefugee:please try this output=data.frame(code=c("E78.5","N08","E78.5","I65.29","Z68.29","D64.9"),patientID=c("34423","34423","34423","34423","34424","34425"),zipcode=c(00718,00718,00718,00718,00718,00719),city=c("NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO"))

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly that you need to find the `code` with the highest frequency by `patientID` and `zipcode`, then `dplyr` might be of use. I think you need to just have the above 3 columns as grouping variables and then `summarise` to get the count of each group. The highest in each row is the mode. The new column gives the count of the mode.

```
# Your reprex data
output=data.frame(code=c("E78.5","N08","E78.5","I65.29","Z68.29","D64.9"),patientID=c("34423","34423","34423","34423","34424","34425"),zipcode=c(00718,00718,00718,00718,00718,00719),city=c("NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO","NAGUABO")) 

library(dplyr)
output %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(patientID, code, zipcode) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mode_freq = n())

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   patientID, code [5]
  patientID code   zipcode  freq
<fct>     <fct>    <dbl> <int>
1 34423     E78.5      718     2
2 34423     I65.29     718     1
3 34423     N08        718     1
4 34424     Z68.29     718     1
5 34425     D64.9      719     1
```

I've included `dplyr::` because I'm assuming you have `plyr` loaded and so function names will conflict.

Update:

To get to your suggested output of the mode, by definition it should be the highest frequency:

```
output %>% 
  group_by(patientID, code, zipcode) %>% 
  summarise(mode_freq = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(zipcode) %>% 
  filter(mode_freq == max(mode_freq))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   zipcode [2]
  patientID code  zipcode mode_freq
<fct>     <fct>   <dbl>     <int>
1 34423     E78.5     718         2
2 34425     D64.9     719         1
```

Comment: i really appreciate ure efforts,but this not the answer i am looking for, i have edited my question and have included the output section,please go through it,waiting for ure reply

Comment: I'll update, but I think in your (new) suggested output the patient count in row 1 should be 2.

Comment: No 1 only,because i am looking for count of distinct patientID with code E78.5